# React Js and Chart Js (Line Chart)

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to add line chart from chart js in react component. I have tried the following code but its showing white screen and no errors. I couldn't figure out what i did wrong. I went through chart.js documentation and got confused. Please give me suggestion how can i display the chart. I'm using react-chartjs-2 version 4.0.0 and chart.js version 3.7.0.

```
import React from "react";
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';

const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Rainfall',
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56]
      }
    ]
  }

  const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
        }
      }
    },
  };

const SavingsChart = () => {
    return (
          <Line
            data={data}
            options={config}
          />
      );
};

export default SavingsChart;
```

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, forgot to register the Chart,js elements https://thecodeframework.com/how-to-use-chart-js-with-react-typescript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should register the chart from `chart.js`

See an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1695r?file=/App.tsx)

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this line in the beginning of your file, it seems to fix this issue:
`import Chart from "chart.js/auto";`

Answer (score 0):

You could create the chart in the `render()` method.

```
render() {
  return (
    <Line 
      data={this.state.data}
      options={this.state.options}
    />
  );
}
```

Please take a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chartjs-2-line-chart?file=index.js) and see how it works with your amended code.